# Facebook API can't retrieve leads. Get error code 100 and error subcode 33

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, lead

I have an application that makes 1 daily query to the API of leads to extract the information.

Following what the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#bulk-read), I send a GET request as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/165XXXXXXXXXXXX/leads?access_token=my_access_token&fields=created_time,platform,id,ad_id,form_id,field_data&limit=600
```

Where `165XXXXXXXXXXXX` is the ID of my lead form and I use Curl to get the data and process it.
Everything worked fine for months, but for 2 days I stopped working and throws me the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '165XXXXXXXXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "ASuIDvuhAhwahA-cWCcnov9"
   }
}
```

I checked the form in the business account, to see if something happened with the form but everything is ok, nothing was modified, the form exists.

I have been checking for 2 hours that it could have happened but the errors exposed by FB do not indicate anything to me. Can anybody help me? What could have happened to stop working?

Comment: Your `token` must include the `leads_retrieval` permission. Also please make sure to upgrade your call, since v3.2 is not available since August 2019 any more - which leads to a forced upgrade internally (thus changing some API behaviours).

Comment: Thank @MichaelHirschler .. One question more, Where can I find this facebook change in the documentation?

Comment: You can always find the changelog here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog (it also covers marketing-api).